# C# DataGrid ContextMenuOpening error if I click on empty space

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

first of all, I'm learning so please don't take it hard on me, please.
I have a DataGrid that takes data from the database and I want to add ContextMenu which takes the first column (Id) so I can use the delete action on the database.

I searched a little and end up by this codes:

For adding ContextMenu XML

```
<DataGrid.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>
      <MenuItem Header="delete" Click="BtnFactorDell">
         <MenuItem.Icon>
           <Image Width="12" Height="12" Source="img/delete.png"/>
         </MenuItem.Icon>
    </ContextMenu>
 </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
```

and for choosing the first column which is my id i use this:

```
string factorselectedid;
private void FactorGrid_ContextMenuOpening(object sender, ContextMenuEventArgs e)
    {

        object item = FactorGrid.SelectedItem;
        factorselectedid = (FactorGrid.SelectedCells[0].Column.GetCellContent(item) as TextBlock).Text;
    }
```

Now I have 1 problem and 1 question, first about the question is what is that TextBlock at the end? because it was TexBox in the codes I found by searching and I get some errors so I randomly change it to TextBlock and it works fine! now I'm confused about what is this.

And about my problem is when I click on empty space on the DataGridview it gives me the error:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
> Parameter name: index'

on the line

```
factorselectedid = (FactorGrid.SelectedCells[0].Column.GetCellContent(item) as TextBlock).Text;
```

What can I do to only work if I click on the files not empty space of my Datagrid?
Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what is that TextBlock at the end?

`GetCellContent(item)` returns a [FrameworkElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement?view=windowsdesktop-5.0), but a FrameworkElement doesn't have a `Text` property. In your case the thing that is returned is a (derivative of) a `TextBlock` which *is* a `FrameworkElement` (TextBlock derives from FrameworkElement), but to access the `Text` property you have to cast the returned `FrameworkElement` to a `TextBlock` first

You might well have seen examples that cast to `TextBox`; those examples would work if the thing being cast *was actually a `TextBox`* - in your case it's *not a `TextBox`* but it is a `TextBlock` (or something else that derives from `TextBlock`), so a cast to `TextBlock` works OK.

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: index'

You just straight attempt to access the first cell (`[0]`) in `SelectedCells` without really knowing if there are any selected cells at all; if there are no selected cells, you'll hit a problem

Consider instead to check if there is at least 1 cell before trying to access is:

```
if(FactorGrid.SelectedCells.Count > 0)
  factorselectedid = (FactorGrid.SelectedCells[0].Column.GetCellContent(item) as TextBlock)?.Text;
else
  e.Handled = true; //suppress the context menu from opening at all
```

I've also added `?` before `.Text` - it will prevent a crash if the thing is ever *not* a TextBlock, but it will mean that `factorselectedid` ends up `null`. Any code that uses `factorselectedid` should perhaps check it for being null `first`

Comment: Thanks for the help it worked but with a small problem if I select a cell that is already there and then I click on empty space, it keeps selecting the last cell I selected, is there a way to fix that problem too? I hope you understand.

Comment: It's what you're asking for, no? It's a selected cell... The problem is essentially that right clicking *outside* of a selected cell doesn't deselect the cells.. You might have to look at doing some code in a mouseclick to clear any currently selected cells if the mouse is not right clicked *on* a selected cell..

Comment: alright ill do it thanks for help man.